# Кодировка JSON файла

Tags: python, json

Есть json файл:

```
{
  "test": [
    {
      "name": "a b"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0095\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b0 \u00d0\u0093\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008c"
    }
  ]
}
```

Пыталась избавиться от проблем с кодировкой, но не выходит.
Почему этот код не сработал?

```
import json
import codecs

with open('test.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Comment: Известно, какая там строка должна быть? Выглядит как будто там просто какой-то мусор (возможно строку кодировали и декодировали через разные кодировки)

Comment: @insolor неизвестно (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут похоже неправильно в самом json данные записаны. У меня получилось декодировать строку так:

```
s = "\u00d0\u0095\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b0 \u00d0\u0093\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008c"
print(s.encode('latin').decode('utf-8'))
```

Вывод: Елена Гемпель

Решал методом подбора фактически. Сначала попробовал избавиться от нулей в кодах символов (т.к. они у были у каждого символа), например `'\u00d0'` превратить в `'\xd0'`. Для этого подошло `s.encode('latin')`. Потом результат попробовал декодировать разными кодировками, подошла кодировка utf-8:

```
>>> s = "\u00d0\u0095\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b0 \u00d0\u00
... 93\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008c" 

>>> s                                                                           
'Ð\x95Ð»ÐµÐ½Ð° Ð\x93ÐµÐ¼Ð¿ÐµÐ»Ñ\x8c'


>>> s.encode()                                                                  
b'\xc3\x90\xc2\x95\xc3\x90\xc2\xbb\xc3\x90\xc2\xb5\xc3\x90\xc2\xbd\xc3\x90\xc2\xb0 \xc3\x90\xc2\x93\xc3\x90\xc2\xb5\xc3\x90\xc2\xbc\xc3\x90\xc2\xbf\xc3\x90\xc2\xb5\xc3\x90\xc2\xbb\xc3\x91\xc2\x8c'


>>> s.encode('ascii')                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)

'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> s.encode('latin')                                                           
b'\xd0\x95\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\x93\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c'


>>> s.encode('latin').decode('cp1251')                                          
'Р•Р»РµРЅР° Р“РµРјРїРµР»СЊ'


>>> s.encode('latin').decode('cp1252')                                          
'Ð•Ð»ÐµÐ½Ð° Ð“ÐµÐ¼Ð¿ÐµÐ»ÑŒ'


>>> s.encode('latin').decode('utf-8')                                           
'Елена Гемпель'
```

Comment: вы кодируете строку отдельно, но сам json файл как перезаписать?

Comment: Конкретно для вашего json: `data["test"][1]["name"] = data["test"][1]["name"].encode('latin').decode('utf-8')`